# Single slash not doing float division

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing the very beginner tutorial of Python and here's something I read fro a forum and tried it in my own editor. The code is as follows

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

def main():
    num = 42 / 9
    print(type(num), num)

if __name__ == "__main__" : main()
```

However, the above program instead of giving me a default output of `4.666666666666667` is giving me  an integer output of just `4`. I've read that the default single slash use in Python 3 will get me floating point output, however I am not sure what's wrong here (why am I getting an int output?).

The other python3 only feature such as string formatting by `'sample {}'.format(n)` is working fine, so I'm not sure if this something to do with my Python3 installation. I'm on mac, so I've the mac's default 2.7 python version as well.

Comment: In `Python 2.x` the expression `42/9` would be integer division, and would result in an `int` which would truncate the decimal part of the division. It will only cast those to `float` in `Python 3.x`

Comment: Try `import sys` and then `print (sys.version)` to see what's running.

Comment: What happens if you use a double slash like ``42//9``

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way this is possible is if you're in Python 2, not Python 3. The formatting feature you reference is also implemented in Python 2.7, so it's very likely that that's what you're using.

To be certain, there's a very easy way to find out:

```
import sys
print(sys.version_info)
```

If you're stuck with Python 2, you can put this at the top of your script to enable true division:

```
from __future__ import division
```

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text (ver 3) as my editor and not sure how it's pointing to the Python2.x version of mac. Shouldn't the shebang point the interpreter path to Python3? `#!/usr/local/bin/python3`

Comment: @user1240679 Sublime doesn't read the shebang to figure out what version of Python to run; it uses the configuration specified by your [build system](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html). You can create a custom build system to point at a given Python installation, or modify the current one, depending on your preferences and setup.

Comment: Ummm, seeems a bit off topic but any idea how can I change this behaviour of Sublime Text for it to pint to Python3? I remember installing a Python3 package from Package Control.

Comment: @user1240679 Open up the build configuration (something like `(...)/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/Python.sublime-build`) and change the path specified in the `"cmd"` property to point at the desired Python executable.

Answer (score 0):

The default interpretation changed from python 2 to 3. You can acutally check it for example on ideone.

```
import sys
print(sys.version_info)
def main():
    num = 42 / 9
    print(type(num), num)

if __name__ == "__main__" : main()
```

[python3.2.2](http://ideone.com/6VcVFV) result:

```
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=2, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
<class 'float'> 4.666666666666667
```

[python2.7.3](http://ideone.com/OHUbm1) result:

```
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
(<type 'int'>, 4)
```

`#!` is used by `bash`-like systems it might be ignored by your run environment.